Powershell Start-Sleep behaves differently with a variable than when using a hardcoded value
I am having trouble in deciphering what is going on with the powershell excerpt below.
Running it using a hardcoded value instead of $timeoutInSecs variable - works as expected (see output at the bottom).  However, if I try to set Start-Sleep using a parameter carrying the very same value  - the script always complete stating the created job has already completed.
All I could think of is maybe because -Seconds requires a double parameter - but that does not make sense - it is implicitly converted into int (and it works with the hardcoded value, so this does not seem to have anything to do with it).
Other than that, I am clueless.
Any help would be appreciated.
This looked related, but OP complains about a slightly different issue.
param(
    [int] $timeoutInSecs
)
Write-Host "timeoutInSecs: [$timeoutInSecs]"
#$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Start-Sleep -Seconds $timeoutInSecs }
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 }
$iteration = 1
while($job.State -ne "Completed")
{
    Write-Host "Iteration: [$iteration] job state: [$($job.State)]"
    $iteration++
    Start-Sleep -s 1
}

Write-Host "job state: [$($job.State)]"
Remove-Job $job

Output when using Start-Sleep with hardcoded value of 5:

Using Start-Sleep as in the commented line, gives as output:


The scriptblock invoked by Start-Job is run in a different scope and doesn’t automatically have access to the current scope’s variables, so $timeoutInSecs is undefined (or $null) in the Start-Job scriptblock. Try $using:timeoutInSecs instead to refer to the variable in the calling scope. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.4#scope-modifiers for details)

In short: Because the script block executes in a different runspace (in a child process, in the case of Start-Job), it knows nothing about the caller's local variables. The simplest way to reference the caller's variable values is with the $using: scope; alternatively, pass values via -ArgumentList. See the linked duplicate for details.

I would use start-threadjob.

@js2010: start-threadjob also uses a script-block. Do you mean it does not suffer from this scoping issue ?

No but it's faster since there's no extra process.

Objects won't be serialized either and methods will stay intact.

@js2010: in other words, nothing to do with the solution to the problem described - just some side notes on advantages of using start-threadjob over start-job.
